# Firebase Functions Deployment Error: Can't Resolve 'Command 'plugin' not found' - Need Expert Advice

Tags: deployment, google-cloud-functions, hadoop-yarn, firebase-tools

I am encountering an issue while trying to deploy Firebase Functions using the Firebase CLI. Whenever I attempt to deploy the functions in my project, I receive the following error

```
Build failed: yarn run v1.22.19  
error Command "plugin" not found.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.; Error ID: e83c667d
Build failed: yarn run v1.22.19
error Command "plugin" not found.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.; Error ID: e83c667d

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        holderOnCreate(us-central1)
        messageOnCreate(us-central1)
i  functions: cleaning up build files...
Error: There was an error deploying functions:
 1. Error Failed to update function messageOnCreate in region us-central1
 2. Error Failed to update function holderOnCreate in region us-central1
```

I have tried several troubleshooting steps, including:

3. Deleting the .yarn and node_modules directories and running yarn (or npm install) again.
4. Verifying that all files are in the correct paths and there are no errors in the code.
5. Ensuring that all dependencies and packages are up to date.
6. Deleting the project and redownloading it from the repository, but the issue persists.
7. Having someone else test the same repository on their machine, and the deployment was successful.
8. I doubled checked with a different test project that I am able to deploy. It seems a combination of my machine and this specific project
9. I've looked through my whole project to see if there's a plugin missing. I can't seem to find any
10. I've googled the error ID and unfortunately nothing is coming up.

FTR here yarn and npm versions I have installed on my machine:
npm - 9.5.1. yarn 3.5.1 (Its weird because the error is displaying the line yarn v1.22.19, and I have literally no idea where that's coming from)

Despite these attempts, I am still unable to deploy the Firebase Functions in my project.

Could anyone provide insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The yarn version in the error is the one that's running on Google's servers and it seems like it's very out of date.

I ended up removing my firebase functions project `yarn.lock` and deployed with `npm run deploy`. That ended up working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this today, and came across https://cloud.google.com/docs/buildpacks/nodejs#using_yarn, you just need to explicitly specify the yarn version in your package.json, e.g.:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "16",
    "yarn": ">= 3.6.1"
  },
```

(replace specific versions as appropriate)